# Incorporate if clause into linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm developing a function that reads at urls in a text file, updates the link, then writes the data back out.

Once the line has been read, I find the 3rd '/', chop the remaining characters from, the link, then make the list distinct. In theory this should be a list of subdomains.

However, I want to check if the line isn't blank and that a 3rd '/' exists.IndexofNth will return -1 if not.

I'm struggling to work out how I can best incorporate this logic, either into what I've got or in a different structure.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var fileName = @"c:\badlinks.txt";

        List<string> urls = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList();

        urls = urls
            .Select(x =>
                x.Replace(x, x.Substring(0, IndexOfNth(x, '/', 3))))
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();

        File.WriteAllLines(fileName, urls);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to filter the items which are not null and has atleast three `/` or you want to do `if-else` operation on each?

Comment: If the line is empty we can't do anything with it so want to ignore it, and if there is no 3rd /, then its already a subdomain, not an inner page, so we want to keep the original string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the list before doing string maninpulation.

```
urls = urls
        .Where(x => x.Length > 0)
        .Select(x => x.Substring(0, IndexOfNth(x, '/', 3) > -1 ? x.Replace(x, x.Substring(0, IndexOfNth(x, '/', 3)))  : x)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

It would be a smart idea to move the logic to a new method to keep your code clean.

```
    urls = urls
        .Where(x => x.Length > 0)
        .Select(x => ManinpulateMyUrl(x))
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();


    private string ManipulateMyUrl(string url) {
      var index = IndexOfNth(x, '/', 3);
      if (index == -1) return url;
      return url.Substring(0, IndexOfNth(x, '/', 3);
    }
```

Comment: If `IndexOfNth` is a custom method, Linq will not execute it. It cannot parse it into Sql.

Comment: @AndreiV `File.ReadAllLines` is not an sql operation.

Comment: @Mathew, I said nothing about `File.ReadAllLines`.

Comment: @Marko Juvančič - Marko, not quite there. This is the explanation I posted above: If the line is empty we can't do anything with it so want to ignore it, and if there is no 3rd /, then its already a subdomain, not an inner page, so we want to keep the original string.

Comment: Anyway guys, it does work as it stands it just doesn't do everything that is required.

Comment: @AndreiV `It cannot parse it into Sql` - There is no need. this is `Linq to objects` not `Linq to Entities` or something. Read the context.

Answer (score 1):

```
urls = urls
        .Select(x => IndexOfNth(x, '/', 3) != -1 
                x.Replace(x, x.Substring(0, IndexOfNth(x, '/', 3))
                : null ))
        .Where(x => x != null)
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

```
urls = urls
       .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
       .Select(x =>IndexOfNth(x, '/', 3)<0?
                   x:
                   x.Replace(x, x.Substring(0, IndexOfNth(x, '/', 3))))
       .Distinct()
       .ToList();
```